# The float property in CSS

Tags: html, css

There is an empty space to the left of the image and I don't know the reason.
This is my HTML code for this section

```css
#features{
  background-color: #f9f6f7;
}

.featuresimg{
  width: 40%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<section id="features">
  <img class="featuresimg" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080.jpg" alt="laptop">
  <h3 class="featuresh">Free, open, simple</h3>
  <p class="featuresp">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
    irure</p>
  <h3 class="featuresh">Powerful tooling</h3>
  <p class="featuresp">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim </p>

</section>
```

[image]

Comment: How wide is the image itself?

Comment: @ChloeAnderson it doesnt matter how wide the image is. CSS declarations wil let it consume 40% of the parents width. If the image is smaller, it will be streched to fit.

Comment: I can not reproduce the issue you describing with the code you provided.

Comment: The extra space to the left may depend on the previous document contents. Please post a big enough HTML snippet to reproduce your problem when clicking in "Run code snippet".

Answer (score 0):

Just use margin-left or padding-left to get rid of the whitespace

```
#features{
  background-color: #f9f6f7;
}

.featuresimg{
  width: 40%;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue with the code, ur image has extra whitespace, please try with a different image. :)

```css
#features{
  background-color: #f9f6f7;
}

.featuresimg{
  width: 40%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<section id="features">
  <img class="featuresimg" src="https://i.ibb.co/tYQMd3V/undraw-proud-coder-7ain.png" alt="laptop">
  <h3 class="featuresh">Free, open, simple</h3>
  <p class="featuresp">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
    irure</p>
  <h3 class="featuresh">Powerful tooling</h3>
  <p class="featuresp">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim </p>

</section>
```

---